# Kotlin: referring to delegate that is not passed by constructor

Tags: kotlin, delegates, delegation, kotlin-delegate

I want to use [Kotlin delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html) in a particular context.

- The delegate should not be passed in the constructor.
- I want to keep a reference to the delegate for later use in the code. From within the method that I override, say `printMessage()`, I still need to call the delegate the same way you'd call `super.printMessage()` in polymorphic inheritance.

I can do the first by simply instantiating an anonymous delegate in the `by` clause (`class Derived() : Base by BaseImpl(42)` using [Kotlin's documentation example](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html)). However,
this prevents me from accessing the anonymous delegate, as there is no way that I know to reference it.

I want to do something similar to the following. The following however doesn't compile with error `'this' is not defined in this context`.

```
class Derived() : Base by this.b {
    
    val b: Base = BaseImpl(42)
    
    override fun printMessage() {
        b.printMessage()
        print("abc")
    }
}
```

I do need a separate delegate for each instance of my `Derived` class. So moving `b` as a global variable is not an option for me.

The closest I got to what I need is with an optional parameter to the constructor. This is not a good option neither, as I don't want to allow the construction of my `Derived` class with arbitrary delegates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using a private primary constructor and a public secondary constructor:

```
class Derived private constructor(val b: Base) : Base by b {

    constructor(): this(BaseImpl(42))

    override fun printMessage() {
        b.printMessage()
        print("abc")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a reference to the delegate, you can also say simply,

```
class Derived : Base by BaseImpl(42)
```